# Не работает jquery validation

Tags: html, jquery

Есть проверка такой формы.
HTML:

```
<form id="registration_form">
        <table>
            <tr style="height: 60px;">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="email@example.com" class="order_input"/>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 60px;">
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="**************" class="order_input"/>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 60px;">
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="repassword" value="" placeholder="**************" class="order_input"/>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" id="mode_c1" name="who" value="1">
                        <label for="mode_c1"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Исполнитель</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <input type="radio" id="mode_c2" name="who" value="2">
                        <label for="mode_c2"><span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Заказчик</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="send"/>
                </td>
            </tr>


        </table>

    </form>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#registration_form").validate({
       rules:{ 
            email:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                email: true,
            },
            password:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 16,
            },
            repassword:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 16,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            who:{
                required: true,
            },
       },
       messages:{
            email:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                minlength: "Поле не может быть меньше 4 символов",
                email: "Введите правильный email",

            },
            password:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                minlength: "Пароль должен быть минимум 6 символа",
                maxlength: 16,
            },
            repassword:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                minlength: "Пароль должен быть минимум 6 символа",
                maxlength: 16,
                equalTo: "Пароли не совпадают"
            },
            who:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",

            },
       }
    });
```

Так вот, проверки всех полей проходит кроме radio button. Почему? что я делаю не так? Подлючаю плагин вот так

```
<script src="<?echo base_url()?>js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: после `HTML` добавьте пустую строку, а то половина кода только видна

Comment: Всё у вас работает: http://screencast.com/t/Bg9YfYQr9Z Проверить можно тут: https://jsfiddle.net/qvr7zwpk/

Comment: @alenkins вот тут можно посмотреть пример. Что то не пашет http://easymoney.website.com.kz/cabinet/registration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если смотреть на ваш пример по указанной ссылке (http://easymoney.website.com.kz/cabinet/registration), видно, что у радио-кнопок установлено свойство `display:none;` Поэтому не работает валидация.
Если вам нужно скрыть эти кнопки, попробуйте сделать это иначе:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    /* плюс размеры и координаты, достаточные для того, чтобы элемент не мешал окружению */
}
```

Comment: уау супер, спасибо. теперь правда криво все показывается. Придется делать через стандартные radio